# Customer Authentication in commercejs

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, commerce.js

You get the problem reading the title. Is there anyway I can sign up customers using commercejs. The documentation is only showing login/logout methods but not sign up.Is there anyway I can do it through commercjs. Or should I use other authentication service like Firebase Auth??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific way to register a user as Commercejs does not store any kind of password.

The only way for registering a user is to use https://commercejs.com/docs/api/#create-customer as per API reference docs. however if you want to integrate some kind of custom auth you should definitely use this reference:

https://commercejs.com/docs/api/#issue-jwt-for-customer

This allows you to issue a JSON web token for a customer directly using your secret Chec API key. This may be a desirable option if you are integrating your own customer authentication, and simply need a token to authorize API requests as your customer with.

I have personally used this method along with Firebase auth.